# Box-and-Whisker plot grouped by year using R

Tags: r, time-series, boxplot

I have timeseries object in R which contains the values of AirPassenger bookings in every month from year 1949-1960. Its easy to plot box plot grouped by month using the command `boxplot(AP ~ cycle(AP))`. I would like to know how to do box plot if we have to group by year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample codes to get you started:

```
ap   <- data.frame(AirPassengers)
year <- rep(seq(1949,1960), rep(12,12))
boxplot(ap$AirPassengers~year)
```